# RadioButton text Android API 16

Tags: android, user-interface, android-radiobutton

I'm having an issue with RadioButton on Android API 16. This issue is not there on newer API level. I found many other problems related to RadioButton in API 16, but none of them resolves my issue.
The text of the RadioButton starts inside the Checkbox, here is a screenshot. I hope someone can help me find a workaround, because I couldn't for now.

The height and width are in "wrap_content"
The left one has a paddingRight="10dp" and the right one has a paddingLeft="10dp"

[image: Text in inside the button]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a workaround since I discovered what is the issue, thanks to sourabh and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739017/2291518)

> On API <= 16 you can set padding left on the radio button to set the padding relative to the radio button's view bounds. Additionally a patch nine background also changes the view bounds relative to the view.

I also used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23348944/2291518) to build my solution for the right button :

**layout.xml**

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:test="some text"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLeft_radioButton" />
```

**values/dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="paddingLeft_radioButton">43dp</dimen>
```

**values-v14/dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="paddingLeft_radioButton">37dp</dimen>
```

**values-v17/dimens.xml**

```
<dimen name="paddingLeft_radioButton">10dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the padding if not necessary to you.. every thing will be on its place.